# How to turn $admin defined in a config file to a mysql varible

Tags: php

Currently, on a forum I am making, I have just defined

```
$admin='adminaccount';
```

However, I want to make the admin perk a variable on the database.

I currently use:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['username']==$admin)
```

but, I have no idea how to turn this into a varible on the mysql.

Comment: `$sql = "SET @admin := '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $admin) . "'";`. This is a way to create a MySQL variable from PHP variable. But it is unlikely you actually want such kind of variable. So please clarify your question.

Comment: Are you just asking how to insert a value into a database?

Comment: I have created a varible called 'admin' on my database. Instead of relying on the $admin defined in the config.php, I want it to rely off the admin in  the database. What command, instead of if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['username']==$admin). do I need?